# HTA - Windows Gadget curved edges

Tags: css, windows, vbscript, hta, windows-desktop-gadgets

I've just written a basic script for a Windows Gadget that runs quietly until it recognises a change.  The one problem I'm encountering is that I want to fancy the Gadget up and have curved edges.  I've tried using a png image with the corners removed but it doesn't work, it always appears as a square box. I've also tried doing this through CSS but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Does anyone know to how create curved edges within HTA/CSS/VBScript? I'm not sure where it would need to happen, it being a Gadget.

Many thanks.

//EDIT

Here's the entire code:

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Chrome Version Checker</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
 APPLICATIONNAME="Chrome Version Checker"
 ID="ChromeCheck"
 VERSION="1.0.0.0"
 BORDER="thin"
 BORDERSTYLE="complex"
 ICON="chrome_updater_256px.ico"
 SCROLL="no"
 SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
 CONTEXTMENU="no"
 NAVIGABLE="yes"
 SELECTION="no"/>
<script language="vbscript"> 
Dim timerID, CurrentTime
Sub Window_OnLoad
  timerID = window.setInterval("RefreshTime", 360000) 'milliseconds
  RefreshTime
End Sub
self.ResizeTo 190,194
 </script>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
    margin: 0;
width: 130px;
height: 134px;
}
span
 {   text-align:center;
font-family: arial;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 12px;
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td>
<span>Installed File</span>
<br />
<span id = "InstallFile"></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<hr>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<span>Remote File</span>
<br />
<span id = "RemoteFile"></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<br /><span id = "StatusMSG"></span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
<html>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
Sub RefreshTime
set xmlhttp = createobject ("msxml2.xmlhttp.3.0")
xmlhttp.open "get", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome", false
xmlhttp.send
strOutput = split(xmlhttp.responseText,"Stable release</a>")(1)
strOutput = split(strOutput," <small>")(0)
strOutput = replace(replace(strOutput,vbcr,""),vblf,"")
strOutput = split(strOutput,"<p>")(1)
    Dim File
    set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")     
    File = FSO.GetFileVersion("C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe")
    if File = strOutput Then
        InstallFile.InnerHTML = File
        RemoteFile.InnerHTML = strOutput
        StatusMSG.InnerHTML = "Up to date"
        document.body.background="tick.png"
        document.body.style.backgroundPosition = "center"
        document.body.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat"
    else
        InstallFile.InnerHTML = File
        RemoteFile.InnerHTML = strOutput
        StatusMSG.InnerHTML = "Not up to date"
        document.body.background="cross.jpg"
        ' ---------------------------------------
        Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
        xmlDoc.load "\\s007\Global\IT\ChromeStandaloneSetup.xml"
        xmlDoc.Async = "False"
        Set nNode = xmlDoc.selectsinglenode ("//ChromeUpdater/Config/Version")
        nNode.text = strOutput
        strResult = xmldoc.save("\\s007\Global\IT\ChromeStandaloneSetup.xml")
        ' ---------------------------------------           
        Dim iURL 
        Dim objShell
        iURL = "https://dl.google.com/tag/s/appguid%3D%7B8A69D345-D564-463C-AFF1-A69D9E530F96%7D%26iid%3D%7B8DD6B5B9-54BE-D8AD-7E05-FBA19DDAA0B0%7D%26lang%3Den%26browser%3D4%26usagestats%3D0%26appname%3DGoogle%2520Chrome%26needsadmin%3Dtrue%26installdataindex%3Ddefaultbrowser/update2/installers/ChromeStandaloneSetup.exe"
        set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        ' --------------------------
        objShell.ShellExecute "chrome.exe", iURL, "", "", 1
        '---------------------------


        Ret = Msgbox("Do you wish to update now?",VBYesNo,"Update Now")
        If Ret = 6 then             
            Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
            objShell.Run("""C:\Program Files\Chrome Updater\ChromeUpdateV2.exe""")
            Set objShell = Nothing

        else    

        End If
End If  
 End Sub
 </SCRIPT>
```

Many thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the code/css you already have?

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` & `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">` does the trick when IE > 8 is installed.

Comment: Thanks, presumibly I'll need to use a transparent PNG for this to work?

Comment: I've managed to get rounded corners, but because it's a Gadget, it still has a white background, so still square -- it's what's beyond the rounded corners I'm trying to remove.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how I rounded the corners in an HTA using CSS.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rounded Corners</title>

    <HTA:APPLICATION
    APPLICATIONNAME="Rounded Corners"
    ID="RestoreHta"
    VERSION="1.0"
    BORDER="dialog"
    BORDERSTYLE="complex"
    INNERBORDER="no"
    SCROLL="no"
    CONTEXTMENU="no"/>

<style type="text/css">

    .b1f, .b2f, .b3f, .b4f{font-size:1px; overflow:hidden;display:block;}
    .b1f {height:1px; background:#ddddbb; margin:0 5px}
    .b2f {height:1px; background:#ddddbb; margin:0 3px}
    .b3f {height:1px; background:#ddddbb; margin:0 2px}
    .b4f {height:2px; background:#ddddbb; margin:0 1px}
    .cf {background: #ddddbb}
    .cf div {margin-left: 5px;}
#DataOptions {
    background-color: #ddddbb;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1.1em;
}

</style>

<SCRIPT Language="VBScript">

Sub Window_Onload
self.ResizeTo 300,300
End Sub


</SCRIPT>       

</head>

<body>
<b class="b1f"></b><b class="b2f"></b><b class="b3f"></b><b class="b4f"></b><div class="cf"><div>
    <div id="DataOptions">
        <table width="100%" height="100">
            <tr>
                <td bwidth="100%"><center>Rounded Corners</center></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    </div></div><b class="b4f"></b><b class="b3f"></b><b class="b2f"></b><b class="b1f"></b>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm quickly realising that CSS doesn't do what I need it to, I've found that using three images (top and bottom with transparency) fits the bill better, however, to add to the complexity, I'm using an image within an "if else" with vbscript, which writes to the background.  If I can use that image as the background that would preferable. The code I posted above is still the same.  Many thanks.